# Long names first for each chapter?

Tags: natbib

I'm writing my thesis using the `memoir` class and `natbib`, with citations such that, at the first occurrence, the full list of authors is given, and "et al." from the second onwards:

```
\usepackage[authoryear, longnamesfirst]{natbib}
```

Since all chapters can be read independently, I was wondering whether there's a way to define the longnamesfirst option such that it applies for each chapter separately rather than the entire document...

Comment: Does the second example in this question help?[latex-bibliography-per-chapter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765209/latex-bibliography-per-chapter)